# VideoJS - Opera & Chrome | Seekbar always restart from zero

Tags: javascript, video.js

When I click on the seekbar, the video always restart **from zero**.
I've seen a similar post on this site [1], and tried  few suggestions, but nothing seems to work.

Not sure why on **Chrome** and **Opera** (same binaries) VideoJS seekbar doesn't work. Maybe it's something related with the  tag since even with other players the seekbar doesn't work (mediaelementjs.com)

On **Firefox** , it works fine. 
Many thanks.

Video URL (any):  http://www.fempton.com/main32/inspire2/stories

```
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.6/video.js"></script>


<div class="ccontainer" > <div class="ccontent"   >
 <div class="ccontent-overlay" ></div>
 <video
    id="fplayer1"
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-16-9"
    controls
    preload="none"
    poster="video/inspire/poster/addiction-opioid03.jpg" 
    data-setup='{"fluid": true}'>
    <source src="video/inspire/addiction_opioid-withdrawal.mp4"></source>
 </video>   
 <div class="content-details fadeIn-top" >
 <h3>Addiction</h3> <p style="font-size:14px;">How addiction works...</p>   
 </div>  
 </div> 
</div>
```

[1] [Seekbar of the video is not working with chrome by using the videojs plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542433/seekbar-of-the-video-is-not-working-with-chrome-by-using-the-videojs-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your server doesn't support byte range headers, which those browsers require to seek. These videos won't play at all in Safari, whichis even stricter about range header support for media requests.

Comment: Thank you for sharing Ben. I use GoDaddy and I'll check the 'byte range' header with them.